# Optaplanner and chaining

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm trying to implement a solution for the following scenario using OptaPlanner:

- We'd like to get from point A to point B
- There is a limited set of edges (our facts; each having a departure and destination itself) that we are allowed to take
- We'd like to find the optimal succession of edges to get from A to B, so that the total distance between edges is minimized
- Thus, any optimal results consists of a set of edges, where the first starts at point A, the last ends at point B, and which are all directly connected

My current model looks like this:

```
@PlanningSolution
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaskAssigningSolution {
    // Our facts: We'd like to go from A to B
    private GeoPoint departureLocation;
    private GeoPoint destinationLocation;

    // Available edges, i.e., database contents
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "edgeRange")
    private List<Edge> availableEdges;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "taskRange")
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    public TaskAssigningSolution(GeoPoint departureLocation, GeoPoint destinationLocation,
                                 List<Edge> availableEdges) {
        this.departureLocation = departureLocation;
        this.destinationLocation = destinationLocation;
        this.availableEdges = availableEdges;
    }

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Task {

    @AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousTask")
    private Edge edge;

    // FIXME: the problem lies here, as I cannot use the edgeRange provider and the taskRange is empty. 
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"taskRange"}, graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    private Task previousTask;

    // Shadow variables
    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousTask")
    private Task nextTask;
}
```

This, however, does not work, as the generated solutions are empty. The taskRange-ValueProvider does not return any tasks, as these are not yet generated.

I am thinking of a task as a realization of an edge. Thus, I am expecting OptaPlanner to generate tasks, where a (random) base edge has been inserted, which in return gets chained to other tasks.

How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use OptaPlanner to find the best path to go from A to B. That's not NP-hard. Use the **A* Search** algorithm (= a better form of Dijkstra). Why? It's not a constraint solving AI problem.

If however, you need to find the optimal route visit multiple locations (so TSP or VRP) then it is NP-hard and then do use OptaPlanner.

Comment: Thank you for putting the problem into perspective. The problem, as described above, might be solved by a path finding algorithm. However, there are many more constraints which are not yet modelled in this simple example, as I wanted to start out with a simple as possible use-case. So, how would you use a path finding algorithm to find a path which optimally uses the available shipping space, is on-time and satisfies several other constraints? I'd think OptaPlanner is a good fit then.